# How to resolve the input lag when using XBOX Series X|S with bluetooth on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, game-controller

I connected my XBOX Series X|S to my Linux machine by following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1653276/913769). Now it has a noticeable lag which makes it hard to use in games. What can I do against it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 28/09/2021:** I updated the firmware of the controller. I also updated the Kernel (5.14 from Ubuntu Mainline) and xpadneo ([rev. 67585b](https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo/commit/67585b3a78202f01ea765deb1981533e4188c1cf)). I did not apply what is written below. After repairing the controller worked flawlessly, without any noticeable lags.

First one needs to locate the configuration file. If the Bluetooth dongle/chipset has address `DONGLE_ADDR` and the gamepad has address `XBOX_ADDR` then the configuration file is `/var/lib/$DONGLE_ADDR/$XBOX_ADDR/info`. On my PC it looks like this: `/var/lib/bluetooth/5C:F3:70:A3:31:C7/44:16:22:6D:6B:E5/info`. This file will contain some gamepad specific stuff (at least the name), so if one is unsure one can guess a bit.

The Bluetooth address of the Gamepad will be shown using the Bluetooth GUI of your distribution.

In that configuration file the following section needs to be added:

```
[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=9
Latency=44
Timeout=216
```

After a reboot the gamepad should work without lag. **Edit:** Using `systemctl restart bluetooth` was sufficient too.

This answer goes back to [this answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1860951#p1860951) in the Arch forum. I thus suspect that it applies to other devices too.